# Why is time.Since returning negative durations on Windows?

Tags: go, time

I have been trying to work with some go, and have found some weird behavior on **windows**. If I construct a time object from parsing a time string in a particular format, and then use functions like `time.Since()`, I get negative durations.

Code sample:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
    "strconv"
)

func convertToTimeObject(dateStr string) time.Time {
    layout := "2006-01-02T15:04:05.000Z"
    t, _:= time.Parse(layout, dateStr)

    return t
}

func main() {
    timeOlder := convertToTimeObject(time.Now().Add(-30*time.Second).Format("2006-01-02T15:04:05.000Z"))
    duration := time.Since(timeOlder)
    fmt.Println("Duration in seconds: " + strconv.Itoa(int(duration.Seconds())))
}
```

If you run it on Linux or the Go Playground [link](https://play.golang.org/p/_3btILKI7Qf), you get the result as `Duration in seconds: 30` which is expected.

However, on Windows, running the same piece of code with Go 1.10.3 gives `Duration in seconds: -19769`.

I've banged my head on this for hours. Any help on what I might be missing?
The only leads I've had since now are that when go's `time` package goes to calculate the seconds for both time objects (`time.Now()` and my parsed time object), one of them has the property `hasMonotonic` and one doesn't, which results in go calculating vastly different seconds for both.

I'm not the expert in time, so would appreciate some help. I was going to file a bug for Go, but thought to ask here from the experts if there's something obvious I might be missing.

Comment: Very close to 5.5 hours.  That likely puts you in India, watch out for local time vs UTC.

Comment: Your layout is incomplete. A `Z` is supposed to be followed by one of `07`, `0700`, `07:00`. See https://golang.org/pkg/time/#pkg-constants.

Comment: @HansPassant Ah, yes, that makes sense. That explains why it worked in my Linux box (timezone was set to UTC). This shouldn't have happened IMO, however. See my reply to Peter.
Also, now that with your help I know it isn't a Windows only issue, do you recommend changing the title of the question? New to SFO.

Comment: @Peter - The time is in [ISO8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_zone_designators), where in a singular Z would mean that it is UTC time and zero offset from GMT. In that sense, the layout does have context of the time zone, but maybe it is not compatible with Go?

Comment: `Z` without an offset format prints a time value *as if* it were in UTC: https://play.golang.org/p/OvmsGJ5NLge. It doesn't actually convert it to UTC before printing.

Answer (score 3):

I think I figured out what the reason for the weird behavior of your code snippet is and can provide a solution. The relevant [docs](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Since) read as follows:

> `since` returns the time elapsed since t. It is shorthand for time.Now().Sub(t).

But:

> `now` returns the current local time.

That means you are formatting `timeOlder` and subtract it from an unformatted local time. That of course causes unexpected behavior. A simple solution is to parse the local time according to your format before subtracting `timeOlder` from it.

A solution that works on my machine (it probably does not make a lot of sense to give a playground example, though):

```
func convertToTimeObject(dateStr string) time.Time {
    layout := "2006-01-02T15:04:05.000Z"
    t, err := time.Parse(layout, dateStr)
    // check the error!
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("error while parsing time: %s\n", err)
    }
    return t
}

func main() {
    timeOlder := convertToTimeObject(time.Now().Add(-30 * time.Second).Format("2006-01-02T15:04:05.000Z"))
    duration := time.Since(timeOlder)

    // replace time.Since() with a correctly parsed time.Now(), because
    // time.Since() returns the time elapsed since the current LOCAL time.
    t := time.Now().Format("2006-01-02T15:04:05.000Z")
    timeNow := convertToTimeObject(t)

    // print the different results
    fmt.Println("duration in seconds:", strconv.Itoa(int(duration.Seconds())))
    fmt.Printf("duration: %v\n", timeNow.Sub(timeOlder))
}
```

Outputs:

```
duration in seconds: 14430
duration: 30s
```